# VS Code false positive errors in Angular html templates

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code with the Angular Language Service extension.  VS Code frequently falsely reports errors in my Angular HTML templates.  I can run the Angular application successfully, run my unit tests successfully and build the application successfully without ever seeing the errors being reported by VS Code.  I have seen multiple types of errors reported but the one I see most often is below.  I do not always see these false positives but it does happen quite often.  Is there a fix for this?

```
'xyz' is not a known element:
1. If 'xyz' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'xyz' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Comment: it sometimes happens when you do change in modules. restarting VS Code works for me.

Comment: @JCCHH, your application works using ng-serve, but it will give you errors when you use `ng build` (the error indicate you that you should add the component to one module and import this module in main.module.ts)

Comment: @Eliseo as i mentioned i am able to run the application, do an ng build and run my test cases and they all work.  the issue is with VS Code, not my code.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using the `selector` of your `component` wrongly. Check your `selector` of your `component` that if it is used as the `html` tag properly somewhere in `html` files.

Comment: as mentioned, i don't see this error when building, testing or running the application so i believe my code is not invalid.